# Can anyone explain me this regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

Can some one please explain me the following expression

```
$input =~ m/\G".*?"(,|$)/gc || $input =~ m/\G[^,]*(,|$)/gc || die;
```

Comment: Which one? Which bit don't you understand?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two regexes here. The first is:

```
\G    # the end of the previous match
".*?" # something in quotes
(,|$) # and a comma, or the end of the string
```

The second will be matched if the first one fails:

```
\G    # the end of the previous match
[^,]* # anything up to the next comma or end of string
(,|$) # and then a comma, or the end of the string
```

My guess is the two regexes are designed to match something which can either be quoted or not quoted, and may be followed by some more items after a comma.

(The `c` modifier means to keep the current position if the matching fails, so the `\G` anchor won't change in the second attempt to match if the first one fails. The `g` modifier sets the position for `\G` for the next match - among other things.)

Answer (score 0):

First one means match every string (that's the `/gc`) between quotation marks followed by a comma or end of string. Second one means match any sequence of zero or more (that's the `*`) non-comma characters (that's the `[^,]`). Note that the `\G` modifier means that each new match must begin right after the previous match.